# Preenchimentos de campos obrigatórios

Tags: c#, .net, string, validação, condição

Como eu faço para obrigar que entre dois campos, pelo menos um deles seja obrigatório (esteja preenchido)? Por exemplo, os campos `Celular` e `Telefone` não podem ser salvos vazios, somente um deles.

Meu código:

```
//..
}
else ((txtNome.Text == "") || (maskedCPF.Text == "") || (maskedCEP.Text == "") || (txtNum.Text == "") || (maskedCelular.Text == "") || (txtTelefone.Text == ""))     
{
  MessageBox.Show("Os Campos com * são de Preenchimentos Obrigatórios!");
}
```

Neste caso ele está obrigando os dois campos (Celular e Telefone) a serem preenchidos. Eu quero que seja possível salvar com o campo celular preenchido e o campo telefone vazio ou vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seria algo assim:

```
else ((txtNome.Text == "") || (maskedCPF.Text == "") || (maskedCEP.Text == "") ||
    (txtNum.Text == "") || ((maskedCelular.Text == "") && (txtTelefone.Text == "")))
```

Usando o operador de *and* (`&&`) só se os dois estiverem vazios é que há algum problema.

Ou, dependendo do caso:

```
if ((txtNome.Text != "") && (maskedCPF.Text != "") && (maskedCEP.Text != "") &&
    (txtNum.Text != "") && ((maskedCelular.Text != "") || (txtTelefone.Text != "")))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/AdditiveCompare.cs).

Comment: É isso mesmo.vlw.

Comment: @enzo dê uma olhada no [tour] além de aceitar uma resposta você pode votar em tudo que achar interessante no site todo.

Comment: @Maniero por qual motivo as condições estão entre parenteses?

Comment: @MateusDaniel Provavelmente porque a pessoa quer deixar mais explícito, eu não faria.

Comment: @Maniero ops, perdão, pensei que isso fazia parte da sua solução, agora que vi que já tava assim rs'

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui de uma maneira diferente, ficou assim:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(!IsPostBack)
 {
   txtNome.Attributes["required"] = "true";
   masked.Attributes["required"] = "true";
 }
}
```